# C++ Returning a member from one of 2 structs using macros or templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I am working on a plugin that runs inside a host program against a proprietary PDK. At times there will be breaking changes in the PDK, so my code uses wrapper classes that allow it to work with more than one version of the host while encapsulating the changes from version to version.

Here is a very simplified example that illustrates the kind of issue I would like to address. Of course, I'm dealing with many more members that 2.

```cpp
struct DataV1 // I cannot modify this
{
   int a;
   float b;
};
struct DataV2 // I cannot modify this
{
   float b;
   int a;
   long c;
};

class DataWrapper // my class
{
private:
   bool _forV1; // determined at run-time
   DataV1 _dataV1;
   DataV2 _dataV2;

public:
   DataWrapper(); // initializes _forV1

   int GetA() const;
   void SetA(int value);
   float GetB() const;
   void SetB(float value);

   long GetC() const { return _dataV2.c } // only exists in v2
   void SetC(long value) { _dataV2.c = value; } // only exists in v2
};
```

I would like to avoid duplicating in every getter and setter the logic that chooses the member from one version of the struct or the other. Note that while the order of members is rearranged, the types and member names are the same. I came up with this macro:

```cpp
#define DATA_ACCESS(MEMBER) const_cast<decltype(_dataV1.MEMBER)&>(([&]() -> const decltype(_dataV1.MEMBER)& \
                                    { return (_forV1) ? _dataV1.MEMBER : _dataV2.MEMBER; })())
```

This allows for a somewhat elegant implementation of the property accessor functons:

```cpp
   int GetA() const { return DATA_ACCESS(a); }
   void SetA(int value) { DATA_ACCESS(a) = value; }
   float GetB() const { return DATA_ACCESS(b); }
   void SetB(float value) { DATA_ACCESS(b) = value; }
```

I am posting this question to see if anyone has a better idea, especially an idea that doesn't involve a macro. Thanks.

Comment: There is already a wrapper: `std::variant`

Comment: I looked at `std::variant` but couldn't see how to use it in each getter and setter without an if statement. Do you have an example of how I would use it in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood exactly but perhaps polymorphism could help? [idea](https://godbolt.org/z/nPbhnfn8E)

Comment: I like the `std::visit` idea. How would the setter side work?

Comment: I believe you already found the documentation for `std::variant`. As this you simply read the given example in the docs and modify the  code for your needs.  Is there any reason why we should repeat the example code here again?

Comment: If you want to post this Get/Set as an answer, I'll give it the check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `std::variant`, you might do something like:

```cpp
class DataWrapper // my class
{
private:
   std::variant<DataV1, DataV2> data;

public:
   DataWrapper(); // initializes _forV1

   int GetA() const { return std::visit([](auto& arg){ return arg.a; }, data); }
   void SetA(int a) const { std::visit([&a](auto& arg){ arg.a = a; }, data); }
    // ...
};
```